# read text file into array and value comparison

Tags: vb.net

i have a text file with the following data:

```
02/26/16 11:36:06.33,0.530, ,934
02/26/16 11:36:06.34,0.540, ,935
02/26/16 11:36:06.34,0.540, ,932
02/26/16 11:36:06.37,0.560, ,935
02/26/16 11:36:06.37,0.570, ,934
02/26/16 11:36:06.38,0.580, ,933
02/26/16 11:36:06.41,0.610, ,932
02/26/16 11:36:06.42,0.610, ,933
02/26/16 11:36:06.43,0.630, ,933
02/26/16 11:36:06.44,0.640, ,932
02/26/16 11:36:06.46,0.660, ,931
02/26/16 11:36:06.47,0.670, ,931
02/26/16 11:36:06.49,0.690, ,933
02/26/16 11:36:06.49,0.690, ,931
02/26/16 11:36:06.51,0.710, ,934
02/26/16 11:36:06.53,0.720, ,927
02/26/16 11:36:06.54,0.740, ,932
02/26/16 11:36:06.55,0.750, ,932
02/26/16 11:36:06.57,0.770, ,933
02/26/16 11:36:06.59,0.790, ,929
```

and i would like to load date(i.e.02/26/16) time(i.e.11:36:06) and the last data (i.e.934) after comma into an array.

if there are 5 consecutive value of the last data are within the range of preset MAX. value and Min. value, a message will be displayed with its correspondent date and time. how do i read and these values into an array and make comparison in vb.net?

the line with most characters is

```
02/29/16 12:24:02.25,10.000, ,1044
```

The incorrect lines are

```
0202/29/16 12:23:32.35,10.110, ,916
02/29/1602/29/16 12:23:25.87,3.630, ,912
02/29/16 12:24:04.84,12.02/29/16 12:24:05.87,13.620, ,1041
02/29/16 12:23:56.45,4.200, ,02/29/16 12:23:57.12,4.870, ,1041
02/29/16 102/29/16 12:23:27.42,5.180, ,913
02/29/16 12:23:48.80,26.560, ,502/29/16 12:23:49.12,26.880, ,503
```

Comment: What you have tried? any demo code? and your paragraph is not clear, `MAX` of which value?

Comment: I haven't tried yet. Regarding to MAX of which value, for instance, let's preset a MAX value as 800 and MIN value as 300, it's ok since 934 is greater than 800 now.  If a value such as 500 is within 800 and 300 then the consecutive data is 1. if next value is 498 then the the consecutive data is 2. and so on.

Comment: Did not tried? are you a beginner in .net?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than read the values into an array, It's easier to add them to a List - and lists are more powerful if you want to do other things.

Add a backgroundworker control to your form and call is `CheckFileData` and a Timer control called `Timer1`

In the code below there is a handler for a button called `btnStartChecking` and one for a button called `btnStopChecking` you can either add these buttons or rename your own. Or if you would prefer another way of doing it, let me know.

Also there is a Label on the form that in my code is `label1`, but you can change that to whatever you want - this shows the status of the data checker and is updated by `Timer1`

```
Imports System.Globalization
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1
    'Your Filename
    Const fileName As String = "C:\Users\Dad\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\readDataFromLiveFile\readDataFromLiveFile\TextFile1.txt"
    'The required date format
    Dim dateFormat As String = "MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss.ff"
    'The range you want to specify goes here
    Dim Min As Single = 300
    Dim Max As Single = 950


    'Structure to make handling of the data easier
    Structure DataLine
        Public [Date] As String
        Public Data1 As String
        Public Data2 As String
        Public Data3 As String
        Public Validated As Boolean
    End Structure


    '02/26/16 11:36:06.59,0.790, ,929
    Private Function GetLastFiveLines() As List(Of String)
        Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName)
        Dim lastline As Integer = lines.GetUpperBound(0)
        Dim templist As New List(Of String)
        If lines.GetUpperBound(0) > 4 Then
            templist.Add(lines(lastline - 4))
            templist.Add(lines(lastline - 3))
            templist.Add(lines(lastline - 2))
            templist.Add(lines(lastline - 1))
            templist.Add(lines(lastline - 0))
        End If
        Return templist
    End Function

    '02/26/16 11:36:06.59,0.790, ,929
    'TODO Try to parse a line and discard it if the data isn's valid
    Private Function SplitLine(line As String) As DataLine
        Dim tempDataLine As New DataLine
        Dim result As DateTime
        With tempDataLine
            .Validated = False
            Dim temp() As String
            'split the line into it's fields
            temp = Split(line, ","c)
            'If there Then are more than four fields then mark the resulting dataline as not validated and exit the function
            If temp.GetUpperBound(0) > 3 Then
                .Validated = False
                Return tempDataLine
            End If
            'if the date can't be parsed, mark as not validated and exit function
            'If Not DateTime.TryParse(temp(0), culture, styles, result) Then
            If Not DateTime.TryParseExact(temp(0), "MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss.ff", New CultureInfo("en-us"), DateTimeStyles.None, result) Then
                .Validated = False
                Return tempDataLine
            Else
                .Date = result.ToString
                .Data1 = temp(1)
                .Data2 = temp(2)
                .Data3 = temp(3)
                .Validated = True
                Return tempDataLine
            End If
        End With

        Return tempDataLine
    End Function


    Private Sub CheckFileData_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles CheckFileData.DoWork
        Dim lastFiveLines As New List(Of String)
        Dim tempdata As Double
        Do
            Dim s As New Stopwatch
            s.Start()
            Dim insideRangeCount As Integer = 0
            'get last 5 lines of file
            lastFiveLines = GetLastFiveLines()
            'try to split them into a DataLine Structure and check the data values
            For Each line As String In lastFiveLines
                Dim tempDataline As DataLine = SplitLine(line)
                'If the line has been validated
                If tempDataline.Validated = True Then
                    'check if the last data item is within the specified range
                    tempdata = CDbl(tempDataline.Data3)
                    Select Case tempdata
                        Case Min To Max
                            insideRangeCount += 1
                        Case Else
                            insideRangeCount = 0
                    End Select
                End If
            Next
            'If 5 or more items have been found, popup a message box and stop checking
            ' You can remove the cancelasync command if you wish and change what happens
            'if 5 items in a row are found by changing the code within this If statement
            If insideRangeCount >= 5 Then
                Dim messageString As String = String.Format("Notification: 5 consecutive samples are with the range: {0} to {1}", Min, Max)
                insideRangeCount = 0
                MessageBox.Show(messageString)
                CheckFileData.CancelAsync()
            End If
            'keep going till the universe goes cold or until someone tells the background worker to stop
            s.Stop()
            Dim p As Long = s.ElapsedMilliseconds
        Loop Until CheckFileData.CancellationPending
        e.Cancel = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        If CheckFileData.IsBusy Then
            label1.text = "Checking"
        Else
            label1.text = "Idle"
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnStartChecking_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStartChecking.Click
        CheckFileData.RunWorkerAsync()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnStopChecking_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStopChecking.Click
        CheckFileData.CancelAsync()
    End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: Don't forget the tick! ;)

Comment: Sorry, I am totally new. How do I open an already opened text file?

Comment: It depends on what you are already doing with the file.  Looking at the data,  do you mean that the file always open because it is being written to constantly,  is is the file already open because the file is being read by some other program,  or some other situation.

Comment: The file always open because it is being written to constantly at 43 line to 90 lines per second.

Comment: Ok and can you access the data as it is being written? If so, you able to post the code that oroganizes the data and writes it to file including to the file into your original question please?

Comment: sorry, I can access the data as it is being written. but since the data is written by an application software. I could not pose the code that organized the data and writes it to file.

Comment: Ah. There might be a problem with file locking and speed of access. Assuming the file is a plain txt file, and obviously they aren't random access and could be locked by a program writing data to the file, you would have to be able to read the whole file, get the last five lines and run the rest of your code, and have time to retry reading within 11 milliseconds. If the file is stored on the same pc that YOUR program is running, this might be possible. If the text file is larger than about 2800 lines, then it would take too long I'm afraid -Based on my 4ghz quad core pc reading from an SSD

Comment: when you say you can access the data as it is being written - how do you do that?

Comment: I see. Thanks for your opinions. I used Excel to import this text file in every 1 second. Unfortunately, in some lines wrong data is written in then.

Comment: I've been looking around and it seems that it might be possible to read the last line of a text file - Does each line ALWAYS the same number of characters?

Comment: Also could you show in your original question how the lines with incorrect data appear please? Thanks.

Comment: each line not ALWAYS the same number of characters.

Comment: Brilliant.  Thanks.  I presume that it's OK to discard any lines of data that can't be parsed properly.  Sorry for all the questions.  :)

Comment: not at all. I deleted two lines of incorrect data because I found both of them are just normal data.

Comment: Thanks. I have some things to do, but I'll be back later to carry on with it.

Comment: Damnit. I cant get my code to work reliably with a text file that is continuously being written to. There has to be a way, but I cant do it. The only other way I can think of  comparing the last 5 samples would be to edit the code in the program that is generating the data. Apologies that I've taken so long to come to this conclusion

Comment: I see. meanwhile I imported txt file via openoffice calc and kept it refresh manually(10-15 time/min), I found no incorrect data in the text file which is continously being written to.

Comment: So you don't need continuous live monitoring then?

Comment: No, I still do need continuous live monitoring.

Comment: Hi again - sorry for the delay - I wasnt very well today - I've tidied up my code a bit and updated the answer- The validation is pretty basic, but should cover most eventualities. In the code there are some event handlers at the end to show how to start and stop the bacgroundworker, and how to see if it is running or not. The main problem that I couldnt solve about being certain that the file reads properly is still not solved, and I'm also not certain that the program can run quickly enough to check every single line. Try it - see how it goes.

Comment: Hi again - Something I forgot to ask, how often does the textfile get updated by the program that generates it? Every time a line is added or every few seoconds. Also is ALL the data kept in the file or only for a certain amount of time. If you dont need to continuously check the data and only need to check it every x seconds or minutes, then the program can be written to be a little more reliable. Also, those lines that are incorrect, are they in the original text file or just in your imports?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. the text file get updated by the program that generated it at 10msec to 20msec.  I am not sure every time a line is added or not. It looks like several tens of lines are added per second.  All the data kep in the file. I do need to continously check the data.  they are incorrect in the original text file.

Comment: I put the revised code in Visual Studio and try to run the code, many error messages are shown. I don't know how to go next.

Comment: It sounds like the  program to check the data really does need to be integrated into the program that generates it

Comment: No, the program does not check the data. I'm getting Four instances of this error at CheckFileData.DoWork, Timer1.Tick, btnStartChecking.Click, btnStopChecking.Click: Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types. (BC30506)

Comment: My apologies, I've updated the answer - and also the code a little.